# How to use enable if with template arguments and parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae, generic-programming

I was working around with c++ templates and came across this piece of code which is using SFINAE using `std::enable_if`. I am facing two issues with this code.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

enum class Type : int { First = 1, Second, Third };

template <Type T>
struct Symbol : public std::true_type {
  using Parent = std::true_type;
  using type = Parent::value_type;
  static constexpr type value = Parent::value;
  static constexpr type GetValue() {
        if constexpr (T == Type::First) return value;
    else return !value;
  }
};


template <bool b>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<b, int>::type;

template <Type T> static constexpr bool IsTradingSymbol() {
  return Symbol<T>::GetValue();
}

template <Type T, EnableIf<IsTradingSymbol<T>()>...>
bool GetErrorForUi(Type A) {
  return true;
}
template <Type T, EnableIf<!IsTradingSymbol<T>()>...>
bool GetErrorForUi(Type A) {
  return false;
}

int main () {
  std::cout << GetErrorForUi<Type::First>(Type::First) << std::endl;
  std::cout << GetErrorForUi<Type::Second>(Type::Second) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

1) Why parameter pack used in `EnableIf<IsTradingSymbol<T>()>...`. If I remove the `...` then the code fails in the compilation. I am unable to deduce the exact error from the trace and why this `...` is needed at all there? (compiled with GCC 7.4.0).

```
enableif.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
enableif.cpp:43:54: error: no matching function for call to ‘GetErrorForUi<First>(Type)’
   std::cout << GetErrorForUi<Type::First>(Type::First) << std::endl;
                                                      ^
enableif.cpp:26:6: note: candidate: template<Type T, typename std::enable_if<IsTradingSymbol<T>(), int>::type <anonymous> > bool GetErrorForUi(Type)
 bool GetErrorForUi(Type A) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
enableif.cpp:26:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
enableif.cpp:43:54: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
   std::cout << GetErrorForUi<Type::First>(Type::First) << std::endl;
                                                      ^
enableif.cpp:30:6: note: candidate: template<Type T, typename std::enable_if<(! IsTradingSymbol<T>()), int>::type <anonymous> > bool GetErrorForUi(Type)
 bool GetErrorForUi(Type A) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
enableif.cpp:30:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
enableif.cpp:43:54: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
   std::cout << GetErrorForUi<Type::First>(Type::First) << std::endl;
                                                      ^
enableif.cpp:44:56: error: no matching function for call to ‘GetErrorForUi<Second>(Type)’
   std::cout << GetErrorForUi<Type::Second>(Type::Second) << std::endl;
                                                        ^
enableif.cpp:26:6: note: candidate: template<Type T, typename std::enable_if<IsTradingSymbol<T>(), int>::type <anonymous> > bool GetErrorForUi(Type)
 bool GetErrorForUi(Type A) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
enableif.cpp:26:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
enableif.cpp:44:56: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
   std::cout << GetErrorForUi<Type::Second>(Type::Second) << std::endl;
                                                        ^
enableif.cpp:30:6: note: candidate: template<Type T, typename std::enable_if<(! IsTradingSymbol<T>()), int>::type <anonymous> > bool GetErrorForUi(Type)
 bool GetErrorForUi(Type A) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
enableif.cpp:30:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
enableif.cpp:44:56: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’
   std::cout << GetErrorForUi<Type::Second>(Type::Second) << std::endl;
```

2) The code is not compiling with icc X86-64 (intel compiler 19.0.1). Does the compiler not support `std::enable_if`sfinae or is it a bug with the intel compiler itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Why parameter pack used in EnableIf()>.... If I remove the ... then the code fails in the compilation. I am unable to deduce the exact error from the trace and why this ... is needed at all there? (compiled with GCC 7.4.0).

Look at `EnableIf<IsTradingSymbol<T>()>`.

It is

```
template <bool b>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<b, int>::type;
```

So is `int` when the condition is `true`, nothing otherwise.

Suppose the condition `IsTradingSymbol<T>()` is true; so

```
template <Type T, EnableIf<IsTradingSymbol<T>()>...>
bool GetErrorForUi(Type A) {
  return true;
}
```

become

```
template <Type T, int ...>
bool GetErrorForUi(Type A) {
  return true;
}
```

Now you have a template function. It requires some, non deducible from the arguments, parameters: a `Type` (`T`), that is mandatory, and a list of integers, zero or more.

You call the function as follows

```
GetErrorForUi<Type::First>(Type::First);
```

So you pass to the function, as template parameter, only a `Type`. Non integers.

This works because the function expect **zero** or more integers.

But when you remove the ellipsis (`...`), the function become

```
template <Type T, int>
bool GetErrorForUi(Type A) {
  return true;
}
```

Now `GetErrorForUi()` expect two template parameter: a `Type` and a `int`. Exactly one `int`, no more zero or more.

Now one integer is mandatory and only one is acceptable.

So now the call

```
GetErrorForUi<Type::First>(Type::First);
```

doesn't works (gives compilation error) because you don't pass the mandatory template `int` parameter.

And also

```
GetErrorForUi<Type::First, 0, 1>(Type::First);
```

doesn't works (after the ellipsis removing; before should compile) because the functions expects exactly one integer and you pass two `int`s.

This should answer also to your second point.

Comment: So the method ```template <typename T, typename... Args>
bool MyFunction(Args&& ...args) {
  return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}```, how is it forwarding the paramete pack to the `tempFunc` ?

Comment: @PiyushVijay - Sorry: I don't understand your question. Anyway, observe that the `MyFunction()` case is completely different: the variadic list of types (`Args...`) is deducible from the arguments of the function (`args...`).

Comment: yeah got that form some other references also. Thanks for the explanation. Also using `int = 0` is solving the intel compiler error but not ellipsis `...`. Why is it happening so?

Comment: @PiyushVijay - yes; it's because you give a default value to the required `int` value; so there is no more needs for an explicit value.

Comment: Are there some good reference sources from where these template concepts can be learned @max66?

Comment: @PiyushVijay - yes... I suppose they are... unfortunately I don't know them. For reference (not learning), I strongly suggest [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Comment: Ok will try to focus on documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional way is:

```
template <Type T, std::enable_if_t<condition_v<T>, int> = 0>
bool GetErrorForUi(Type A);
```

And not

```
template <Type T, std::enable_if_t<condition_v<T>, int>...>
bool GetErrorForUi(Type A);
```

So after Substitution, it is

```
template <Type T, int /*unnammed*/ = 0>
bool GetErrorForUi(Type A);
```

```
template <Type T, int /*unnammed*/...>
bool GetErrorForUi(Type A);
```

If Substitution Failure happens, it is Not An Error (SFINAE), and those overload are discarded

Comment: but why `= 0` or `...` is needed at all. Is there some conceptual reason I am missing here or is it the factual thing that we should use enable_if this way only. And why it is not needed here ```template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, bool>::type
IsThisRight(T a)```